# No Password Input Field on unity-greeter Login Prompt

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, lightdm, ubuntu-gnome, unity-greeter

I know this has been asked before, but bear with me, this one is a little different.

On session login screen (lightdm) there is no password input field to type password into. **This only happens when I'm in single screen mode, when my laptop is connected to a dock with 2 other monitors attached I get a password input field.** When I type my password it is being accepted and I can log in although I can't see that I'm actually typing a password. Fingerprint-based auth also works.

[image: lightdm greeter after boot]

Picking another user, like Guest works and I'm being presented a password input prompt:

[image: Guest user picked]

Going back in the user picker from Guest to my own user seems to break something, the rendering is broken even more and I can't log in any more, not even with fingerprint auth:

[image: Own user selected again]

Switching LightDM from `unity-greeter` to `lightdm-gtk-greeter` works fine and I get the password input field but it looks ugly and I would like to keep using `unity-greeter` if I can. This is kind of a cosmetic problem, I can still use my system. This is also a non-issue for the Gnome3 session because Gnome3 seems to use a different lock screen when going to sleep and presents me a different greeter when it wakes up.

System:

- Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 (with gnome3-staging PPA)
- Nvidia driver 378.13 (same problem with 375.39 and 381.09)